# Add join works, join field doesn't

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, attribute-joins

My input join field and output join field are text type, and my problem is that when I use "Add Join" all joins ok, but if I want to use "Join field" there are some records with Null, it seems like it doesn't recognize that the text are the same in fields from both tables.

Comment: If the join works just for some records it is likely that you have slight differences in the records not joining. Take one of the cases where it is not working and copy and paste the text of both sources in a text editor. You may have cases of spaces, punctuation, misspellings, case sensitivity...

Comment: The names are exactly the same in both tables, there's no spaces

Comment: Do the field types of common field match?

Comment: Yes they are both type text